# Vertical ScrollViewer Shifts the ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, treeview

**Context**

I have a `TreeView` customised to our themes and needs. The last level tree hierarchy is list of elements (Thumbnail with text below). They are arranged in two columns and two elements in a row. This is achieved using a `ListBox` with `UniformGrid` as `ItemsPanel`. I have a `ScrollViewer` for the whole `TreeView`. The `ListBox` itself is contained in the penultimate `TreeViewItem` which has an overloaded style (see below). This is required so that I can put two element per row and remove `Expander` and indentation etc.

**Problem**

When the number of items increase in the `TreeView`, the scroll bar appears but it shifts the `ListBox` to left side. If I collapse some elements the scroll bar disappears and the items (Thumbnail with text) shift to right again.

**What I tried**

I have tried specifying `Width`, `MaxWidth` and disabling `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` on `ScrollViewer`, `TreeView` and `ContentPresenter` for `ListBox`. But still now luck. I have no idea how can I prevent the items from shifting to left when `ScrollViewer` appears.

**ListBox XAML**

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Background="Black" SelectionMode="Extended" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MaxWidth="230">
     <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
             <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
             <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
             <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
             <Setter Property="Width" Value="95"></Setter>
             <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=OneWayToSource}"></Setter>
             <Setter Property="Template">
                 <Setter.Value>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                         <ContentPresenter MaxWidth="230" Width="230" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"></ContentPresenter>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
         </Style>
     </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <UniformGrid Columns="2" Width="220" Margin="0,15,0,0"></UniformGrid>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
 </ListBox>
```

**Penultimate TreeViewItem Style**

```
 <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="myStyle">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                 <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Margin="{Binding Converter={StaticResource mySNThumbnailItemHostMarginConverter}}" 
                                   MaxWidth="230" Width="230" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"></ContentPresenter>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

[image: Sample Output]

How can I achieve this? Thanks for help!

Comment: You are setting fixed widths on your ListBoxItems, therefore, when the Scroll Bar becomes visible, there isn't enough room for it, so it pushes the content to the left. Consider removing fixed widths.

Comment: @MikeEason Thanks for replying. I tried that but didn't help. Any other suggestions?